# Count co-occurence of duplicate words with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm very new to scala and right now I'm struggling to count the co-occurence frequency of words for each RDD of Dstream.
So far my code is working when I don't have duplicate words but when I do it skips them, and when I remove the filter function it counts each word on itself...

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

this is my input:

> like pig like hive

this is my code with the filter:

```
 val coOccurrenceCountsB = rdd.flatMap { line =>
          val words = line.split("\\s+").filter(word => word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && word.length >= 3)
          words.flatMap { word1 =>
            words.filter(word2 => word2 != word1).map(word2 => ((word1, word2), 1))
          }

      }.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

and my output:

> ((pig,hive),1)
> ((hive,like),2)
> ((like,hive),2)
> ((pig,like),2)
> ((hive,pig),1)
> ((like,pig),2)

My output without the filter:

> ((pig,hive),1)
> ((pig,pig),1)
> ((hive,like),2)
> ((like,hive),2)
> ((pig,like),2)
> ((hive,pig),1)
> ((like,like),4)
> ((like,pig),2)
> ((hive,hive),1)

what i want:

> ((pig,hive),1)
> ((hive,like),2)
> ((like,hive),2)
> ((pig,like),2)
> ((hive,pig),1)
> ((like,pig),2)
> **((like, like), 2)**

My Answer based on pasha701 answer:

```
val coOccurrenceCountsB = rdd.flatMap { line =>
  val words = line.split("\\s+").filter(word => word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && word.length >= 3)
  val indexed = words.zipWithIndex
  indexed.flatMap { case (word1, index1) =>
    indexed
      .filter { case (_, index2) => index1 != index2 }
      .map { case (word2, _) => ((word1, word2), 1) }
  }
}.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by position can be applied instead of value, with `zipWithIndex`:

```
val words = line.split("\\s+").filter(word => word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && word.length >= 3)
val indexed = words.zipWithIndex
val result = indexed.flatMap { case (word1, index1) =>
  indexed
    .filter { case (_, index2) => index1 != index2 }
    .map { case (word2, _) => ((word1, word2), 1) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

I had to get rid of val result as it was giving a type mismatch error. I've updated my question with the answer now.